# Will browsers throw some Error if cookie size will be out of browser limit?

Tags: javascript, cookies

If cookie size is out of browser limit Will browsers throws some Error?

Comment: If you are using cookies and are even thinking this is a problem consider changing to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: just test it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***The browser just crashes*** !

Webpage becomes un-responsive and finally browser crashes, you can try this yourself :

1. Go to this [website](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/)
2. Try setting a cookie with a very large size (a character repeated n
   number of times )
3. See for yourself

Highlights of the article shared above :

*If you want to support most browsers, then don't exceed 50 cookies per domain, and don't exceed 4093 bytes per domain (i.e. total size of all cookies <= 4093 bytes)*

Typically, the following are allowed:

- 300 cookies in total
- 4096 bytes per cookie
- 20 cookies per domain
- 81920 bytes per domain*

*Given 20 cookies of max size 4096 = 81920 bytes.

Comment: its confusing...max size of a domain is 4043 bytes or 81920 bytes.?

Comment: Don't understand why browser didn't give opportunity for the developers to have  control on the cookies limits errors.

Comment: I'v made test suggested by you, and as I see: Chrome browser will crash, Firefox and  Microsoft Edge, will throw 'out of memory' exception. Thank you for the link with tests.